# iOS: Compare the image against image

Tags: ios, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-comparison

I am looking for something interesting but not sure whether it's possible or not in iOS. Ideally I want to take a photo of any tree using iPhone and want to recognize what tree is it! This is beyond the scope but I would be happy to research if someone suggest me if this is possible. Next I have nailed down problem to take a photo of leaf and compare that leaf against the 1000s of leaves stored on the iPhone. Still not sure if there is accurate way to make this comparison either. I am fine if we get something like 70% matching or so! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking is a rather complex problem in machine vision, particularly the identification of an arbitrary tree. The folks at dsp.stackexchange.com might be able to better help you here, but you're going to need to refine this a bit before asking them (and search around there for general object recognition techniques). For now, OpenCV would be your best bet for doing this kind of processing, but you'll need to find out how to apply it to this. I'm working on something much faster, but that won't be ready any time soon.

Comment: There's an app out there that ostensibly does this. It's called LeafSnap. I believe the image processing happens on the server side, or at least some of it. http://leafsnap.com/